# Configure SAML SLO for Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can I set the SLO URL for Snowflake SAML integration? I want Snowflake to log out of the identity provider if the user logs out of Snowflake.

I've searched the documentation at https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-security-integration.html#saml2-required-parameters and I can't seem to find anything related to the SLO URL.

Comment: It is possible, see this [example](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-fed-auth-configure-idp.html#step-3-enable-global-logout-optional)

Comment: @Sergiu That example is for logging out of Snowflake if the user logs out of the IdP. I need it to log out of the IdP if the user logs out of Snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

Am sure you have tried this already:
Okta documents say if SLO is not available then the main URL can be used -->https://help.okta.com/en/prod/Content/Topics/Apps/Apps_Single_Logout.htm

Comment: Where in Snowflake would I configure that URL?

Comment: the config is within Okta